# How to work with setInterval and constructor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to work with setInterval and constructor's method. 
console.log is showing undefined. Can anyone explain why and how to access the variable of constructor from setInterval.

```
var aa=new test();
var bb;
window.onload= function(){
    bb=setInterval(aa.b,1000);
}   
function test(){
    this.a=1;
    this.b=function (){
        console.log(this.a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a function like this:

```
setInterval(() => aa.b(), 1000);
```

The reason your way doesn't work is that you pass the b function to the setInterval, but then it lose it's `this` reference, so `this` becomes the global window object, and window.a is undefined.

Wrapping it in a function make the `this` be `aa` as you invoking the function on the `aa` object.

If you don't want to wrap your function in another function, you can also use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
setInterval(aa.b.bind(aa), 1000);
```

Here the `this` is forced to be `aa`.

Comment: Oh com'on! :) I answered about "bind version" just before you :)

Comment: Missed that. +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

```
setInterval(aa.b.bind(aa),1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The others are correct - the `this` refers not to `test` instance anymore, an easier way to fix (correctly) this is using a new variable:

```
var aa=new test();
var bb;
window.onload= function(){
    bb=setInterval(aa.b,1000);
}   
function test(){
    var self = this; //keep the right 'this'.
    this.a=1;
    this.b=function (){
        console.log(self.a); //changed, `self` instead of `this`
    }
}
```